# Find-all-facts function returns "Unable to find deftemplate XXX", after i have introduced modules

Tags: clips

I changed my expert system core to use named modules.

Now when I call `find-all-facts` function it always returns

`"Unable to find deftemplate 'XXX'"`.

For example my query looks like:

`(find-all-facts ((?f  PlannerGoal )) TRUE)`

PlannerGoal deftemplate is located in PLANNING module.

I also tried to do:

`(find-all-facts ((?f  PLANNING::PlannerGoal )) TRUE)`

But nothing changes. I run this function after (run) command has been issued.

Seems like i dont understand something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the current module in which you're executing the **find-all-all-facts** command does not import the PlannerGoal deftemplate.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 4/1/19)
CLIPS> (defmodule PLANNING (export ?ALL))
CLIPS> (deftemplate PlannerGoal (slot id))
CLIPS> (defmodule MAIN (import PLANNING ?ALL))
CLIPS> (assert (PlannerGoal (id 1)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (PlannerGoal (id 2)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (find-all-facts ((?f PlannerGoal)) TRUE)
(<Fact-1> <Fact-2>)
CLIPS> (defmodule EMPTY)
CLIPS> (find-all-facts ((?f PlannerGoal)) TRUE)
[PRNTUTIL1] Unable to find deftemplate PlannerGoal.
CLIPS> (focus PLANNING)
TRUE
CLIPS> (find-all-facts ((?f PlannerGoal)) TRUE)
(<Fact-1> <Fact-2>)
CLIPS> (get-current-module)
PLANNING
CLIPS>
```